# Display Updated Page using Ajax/JQuery PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

This would be a common question but what I'm looking for is:
My PHP Script does:

- Read a remote page using cURL
- Update every 20 Seconds
- I want to auto update a div(Not whole page), (Which is populated using cURL) every 20 seconds.

I've read many solutions but that doesn't show updated data in source code (Crawl-able form).

Pls suggest me a solution how to update a div with cURL updated data, and that should populate/include in my page's source code.

Let me know if anything is unclear. sorry for bad english :(

Comment: We need to see your code, so we could say what's wrong there!

Comment: I'm looking for the way how can i do it? I'm currently refreshing whole page to show updated content

Comment: Usually when you alter the info into a part of a DOM document without reloading the page this won't be reflected on the document's source code. I presume this is because source code is readed by the browser when you load the page and it doesn't upload when you make changes to the DOM (it would be probably very costly to be always checking for any DOM alteration on the background just to update the source code).

Comment: @Bardo Thanks you for understanding what i need at least :)
See http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/06/simple-ajax-commenting-system/demo.php this script does the same what I'm looking for.
Can't I have some thing like that for my auto updating content?
I'm zero in JQuery

Comment: This commenting system is appending data, you need to reload the data as I understood, see my answer below

Comment: The url you posted don't refresh source code until you reload the page. If you want this behaviour you need to alter not only the data on client's DOM, you need to post the new data to your server so when you reload the page the new data is fetched from the server.

Comment: @Bardo are you mentioning long pulling? let's not make this hard for him, he just wants to reload the data every 20 seconds, a simple jquery load() would do the trick for him.

Comment: @behz4d I'm not suggesting long pulling or other Comet technique. I simply state that if he want to have the source code updated with user input he had to push that data to server in order to it being retrieved from there when the page is reloaded. If the info isn't on the server (that's only modified on client code), when the reload happens the source code will be the same that on the previous call.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your cURL PHP codes into a new file named "reloader.php", in your main page, also put the source codes which reads the data(cURL stuff) in a div "id = to_be_reloaded", in your main page add these:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#to_be_reloaded').load('reloader.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 20000); // refresh every 20000 milliseconds(20 seconds)
</script>
```

Comment: No, it's not, this just update the DIV with id as "to_be_reloaded", and thats where you already had your first cURL fetched data while you loaded the page, so it clears that div and reloads it again from reloader.php which bring you the new data(every 20 seconds)

Comment: This works like a charm but the problem is, I do not want to display the file i'm using to display data.
Any other method or solution  plz ???

Comment: @nandla what do you mean!? It shows the files source code? this should just show the out put, give more explanation

Comment: Dear! Thank you for the reply.
$('#to_be_reloaded').load('URL TO FILE.php').fadeIn("slow");
I don't want to mention URL TO FILE.php, This will breach my creativity to copiers. I do not want to tell the world which file i'm including in my page.
Hope you get it.
Let me know if further explanation is required

Comment: @nandla You need to send a request, as far as I know there is no way of hiding request addresses, unless you want to do some encryption on that URL which still could be compromised... the best solution on this is that not allowing other users send request to "URL TO FILE.php", on that php page you could answer to the requests which is sent ONLY by your own page "index.php", there is lots of ways for doing this, checking referrers, generating valid IDs in db and expire them after they used and etc...

Comment: Yeah I 'd have adopted this so that no one can access outside of my domain

Answer (score 0):

I know you need it for commenting system and
The workaround is use `setInterval` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 setInterval(function(){
     $.ajax({
       url:'PUT YOUR URL',
       success:function(data){
          $('#comment').append($(data).fadeIn());
       }
     });
 }, 20000);
</script>
```

Anything else ... 
good luck

Comment: I want to refresh a div from cURL data, and i do not want to append instead i want to overwrite (Update)